# How to configure email notifications in Redmine?

Tags: smtp, gmail, redmine

I have installed Redmine in offline mode by using Bitnami and configured email notifications as follows, as says in [Redmine: Email Configuration](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration)

My environment:

```
Environment:
    Redmine version     2.3.2.stable
    Ruby version        1.9.3-p231 (2012-05-25) [i386-mingw32]
    Rails version       3.2.13
    Environment         production
    Database adapter    Mysql2
    Redmine plugins:    no plugin installed
```

Part of configuration.yml:

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:    
      address: ...here smtp.domain or ip of smtp- server...
      port: 25
      domain: ...some domain...
      authentication: :login
      user_name: ...name@domain...
      password: "..."
```

In the same domain runs the mail server.

I requested my password from Redmine UI:

[image]

However, the message does not come.

What I have in production.log:

```
Started POST "/redmine/account/lost_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-22 21:38:21 +0400
Processing by AccountController#lost_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"252n1tBNbFP/BzQ6spgzVTx/yKnltmhd9jHhzcgyTwU=", "mail"=>"...name@domain...", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered mailer/lost_password.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
  Rendered mailer/lost_password.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.0ms)
Redirected to http://localhost/redmine/login
Completed 302 Found in 886ms (ActiveRecord: 68.0ms)
Started GET "/redmine/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-22 21:38:22 +0400
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered account/login.html.erb within layouts/base (7.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 16.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

When I tested this configuration outside the intranet, I used the gmail. Part of configuration.yml:

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:    
      address: smtp.gmail.com
      port: 587
      domain: gmail.com
      authentication: :login
      user_name: ...name@gmail.com
      password: "..."
```

When I requested the password in this configuration, the message has come.

message:

```
To change the password, click on the following link:
http://localhost:3000/account/lost_password?token=dd36a006157cfa8d208ba11822c9283f14ef5f65

User: alexey

You have received this notification because you have either subscribed to it, or are involved in it.
To change your notification preferences, please click here: http://hostname/my/account
```

What I see in production.log now:

```
Started POST "/redmine/account/lost_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-22 22:09:40 +0400
Processing by AccountController#lost_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"252n1tBNbFP/BzQ6spgzVTx/yKnltmhd9jHhzcgyTwU=", "mail"=>"...name@domain...", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered mailer/lost_password.text.erb within layouts/mailer (3.0ms)
  Rendered mailer/lost_password.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.0ms)
Redirected to http://localhost/redmine/login
Completed 302 Found in 2769ms (ActiveRecord: 73.0ms)
Started GET "/redmine/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-22 22:09:43 +0400
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered account/login.html.erb within layouts/base (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

So,

- If I use gmail, the message are sent and delivered
- If I use other, the message are not sent or sent but not delivered

What I'm doing wrong? How to configure email notifications in Redmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the syntax.

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: ********.com 
      port: 25
      domain: ********.com
      enable_starttls_auto: false  
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "#############@***.com"
      password: "####"
```

Also the keyword 'production' should be environment specific.

I referred their official configuration page.
https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration